# in Cesium, dynamic rotating compass resets backwards to 0 when it passes 360

Tags: javascript, css, cesiumjs

I have this simple code to animate a compass icon to reflect the current orientation of the camera in Cesium, whenever I pass through 360 degrees however, the compass spins left to reset at 0, rather than spinning through. Code is below:

```
viewer.camera.changed.addEventListener(rotateCompass);
viewer.camera.moveEnd.addEventListener(rotateCompass);

function rotateCompass() {
    document.getElementById('compass').style.transform = 
        `rotate(-${viewer.camera.heading}rad)`;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution, bound listener to `viewer.clock.onTick` instead of on the camera changes itself. compass now reflects camera heading quite nicely with just 1 listener and 1 function:

```
viewer.clock.onTick.addEventListener(rotateCompass);

function rotateCompass() {
    compass.style.transform = `rotate(${viewer.camera.heading}rad)`;
}
```